# Can you update the content (text) property of a ContentDialog?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I need to update the text inside a ContentDialog after it's been displayed.

Is this thing possible ?

Thanks.

Comment: You could use the Content property of ContentDialog to perform this operation, but ContentDialog represents a modal dialog, which means the app window is blocked until the dialog is closed by the user. So that there is no way to trigger the update action after it's been displayed except for the contentdialog related behavior(for example, clicking the button of the dialog box). So you need to consider how and when to trigger the event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this thing possible ?

No, calling `ShowAsync` of the `ContentDialog` returns a `Task` that doesn't complete until the dialog has been closed by the user.

If you have a requirement to change the text in the dialog after it has been displayed, you should consider using your own custom dialog window with data bindings instead of using the `ContentDialog` API.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can!

I did it this way. Unfortunately, I don't get the ContentDialog passed as a parameter through the thread call. So I decided to store it as a class variable. (m_ContentDialog)

```
fire_and_forget MainWindow::ConnectClicked(IInspectable const& sender, RoutedEventArgs const& args)
{
    auto strong_this = get_strong();
    m_isConected = !m_isConected;
    if (m_isConected) {
        ConnectButton().IsChecked(true);

        m_devices.clear();
        m_ContentDialog.XamlRoot(MainGrid().XamlRoot());
        m_ContentDialog.RequestedTheme(m_theme);
        m_ContentDialog.Title(box_value(L"Scan Devices"));
        m_ContentDialog.Content(box_value(L"Please wait.."));
        m_ContentDialog.PrimaryButtonText(L"OK");

        thread consumer = thread(&MainWindow::InitDevicesDialog, this);
        consumer.detach();

        co_await m_ContentDialog.ShowAsync();

        co_await ui_thread;
        m_ContentDialog.Title();
        
    }
    else {
        ConnectButton().IsChecked(false);
    }
    co_return; // Exit
}

fire_and_forget MainWindow::InitDevicesDialog()
{
    auto strong_this = get_strong();
    //Log::debug(format("sdf {}", cd));
    
    co_await ui_thread;
    while (!m_ContentDialog.IsLoaded()) {
        co_await 1ms;
        co_await ui_thread;
    }

    string content = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        auto& d = initDevice(i);
        if (d.name != "") {
            content += format("Device {}: Serial {}\n", i, d.name);
        }
        else {
            content += format("Device {}: not present \n", i);
        }
        co_await ui_thread;
        m_ContentDialog.Content(box_value(to_hstring(content)));
        m_ContentDialog.UpdateLayout();
        co_await resume_background();
    }
    co_await ui_thread;
    m_ContentDialog.Title(box_value(L"Scan Finished"));

    co_return; // Exit
}
```